# Splitting array into multi dimensional in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need help. I hava an array like in JavaScript
`let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9];`
I have to change it to split to multi dimensional `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`
So what's the method to have this.

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks